# why my NSButton catch mouse event when it hidden?

Tags: macos, cocoa, events, mouse

I want my mainwindow has a different status, so I create two `NSViews`. One is called `A_view` other is `B_view`. I add an `NSButton` called `A_button` to `A_view`.

When clicked the `A_button`, `A_view`  is hidden and `B_view` display. When click other button which added into mainwindow, the status change and `B_view` is hidden, `A_view` display. However, I find that when `A_view` is hidden, I click `B_view` in position which `A_button` is ,the `A_Button` still catches the mouse event.

Anyone could tell me why and what can I do which prevent this happen? thank you!
I am happy to make friends this is my mail gohamgx@gmail.com. I hope to communicate with you about some cocoa questions.

Comment: Thanks for providing your gmail id in question....huhh. this is not a friendship or go4Date kind of site. If you want to give your email, give to those who want and mention it in your profile. not in the question.

Comment: sorry,i just want to know the answer quickly

Comment: Hidden button cant take actions unless you are calling action method explicitly. For surety even you can disable the button. and let me know what happens now.

Comment: if i disable the button,its action method is not called.

Comment: so your problem solved!!!

Comment: So should i Post this as an answer? and will you accecpt and vote me up?

Comment: i don't know where i vote u up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hidden button cant take actions unless you are calling action method explicitly.

For surety even you can disable the button.

And let me know what happens now